# OSHW board for Artix 7 FPGA XC7A15T

Tags: hardware

I am looking for an Open Source Hardware (OSHW) board for an Artix 7 FPGA XC7A15T but couldn't find one. I would be grateful if someone from this community can guide me. I would prefer a design in eagle!

Comment: Hey there! Generally, we don't allow software or hardware recommendations over here, but you may have some luck asking this question at [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com) if you can ask a specific question: you need to ask for a product. Anyways, welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Designing FPGA boards is not an easy task, do you have experince with such big chips?

Especially, the power supply is hard work. Xilinx offers evaluation boards which are also reference designs. Designers use these boards and supplied schematics to design custom boards.

Maybe you should ask at [EE.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com), too.